# (Android) Trying to use spinner selection to toggle image in imageview, but cannot resolve imageview in onItemSelected

Tags: java, android, xml

As stated in the title I am trying to write code that toggles the image displayed in an ImageView based on the user's selection in a spinner (the page has 3 spinners but only one is meant to toggle the image). I've checked several solutions to similar problems here and almost all of them instantiate the ImageView object in the onCreate method and set the drawable resource used in the spinner listener's onItemSelected method. However, when I try to reference the ImageView object in the onItemSelected method I get an error stating 'cannot resolve symbol'. Clearly I am missing something but I cannot figure it out.

Both ImageView and Spinner in date_location.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="118dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
    android:background="#ff7c7c "
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/locationSpinner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/location1" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/locationSpinner"
    android:layout_width="172dp"
    android:layout_height="46dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="#ff7c7c "
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dateSpinner"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"></Spinner>
```

String array used in strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="locations">
    <item>Arlington, PA</item>
    <item>Burmingham, PA</item>
    <item>Essex, PA</item>
</string-array>
```

Snippet of code from onCreate method in LocationDate.java:

```
final ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.map);

Spinner locationSpin = findViewById(R.id.locationSpinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> locationA = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.locations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
locationA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
locationSpin.setAdapter(locationA);
locationSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

code in onItemSelected from LocationDate.java:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    switch (parent.getId())
    {
        case R.id.locationSpinner:
            location = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String[] locationsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);
            if (location == locationsArray[0])
            {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.location1);
            }else if (location == locationsArray[1])
            {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.location2);
            }else if (location == locationsArray[2])
            {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.location3);
            }
        case R.id.dateSpinner:
            showDate = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        case R.id.timeSpinner:
            showTime = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }
}
```

Just in case it is useful here is the full LocationDate.java class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class LocationDate extends AppCompatActivity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
{
String location = "";
String showDate = "";
String showTime = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.date_location);

    final ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.map);

    Spinner locationSpin = findViewById(R.id.locationSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> locationA = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.locations, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    locationA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    locationSpin.setAdapter(locationA);
    locationSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Spinner dateSpin = findViewById(R.id.dateSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dateA = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.dates, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    dateA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dateSpin.setAdapter(dateA);
    dateSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Spinner timeSpin = findViewById(R.id.timeSpinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> timeA = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.times, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    timeA.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    timeSpin.setAdapter(timeA);
    timeSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    Button proceed2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    proceed2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra("Location", location);
            data.putExtra("Date", showDate);
            data.putExtra("Time", showTime);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK ,data);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    switch (parent.getId())
    {
        case R.id.locationSpinner:
            location = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String[] locationsArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.locations);
            if (location == locationsArray[0])
            {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.location1);
            }else if (location == locationsArray[1])
            {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.location2);
            }else if (location == locationsArray[2])
            {
                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.location3);
            }
        case R.id.dateSpinner:
            showDate = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        case R.id.timeSpinner:
            showTime = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
{

}
}
```

^ the formatting was slightly messed up upon pasting here but hopefully it's still plenty readable.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol cannot be found because you're declaring `final ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.map);` in the scope of your `onActivityCreate(Bundle)` method, but you're not defining it inside `onItemSelected(...)` when trying to actually use it.

Just move that declaration into `public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` before you try to access it, and the symbol will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I've just done this and it does in fact resolve the symbols, however the spinner still isn't toggling the images. Is there another error in my approach to making this work?

Comment: Well, since your `R.array.locations` is already ordered, there's no reason to try and lookup `parent.getItemAtPosition(position)` for the value. You already know `if (position == 0)` then you want `R.drawable.location1`. But you should try logging what the values are (or setting breakpoints) at the point in which an item is selected to see if what you're expecting to happen is actually happening

Comment: Ohhhhh yes! Checking for (position == 0), 1, 2 etc. was the fix I needed. Thank you so much!